# Is it possible to add a tag to a Worker within it?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to add a tag to a `Worker` **within** it (not via a `Builder`).
I've tried doing that the following way:

```
class MyWorker(...): Worker(...) {
  init {
    tags.add("MY_TAG")
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are accessible in a `Worker` through its [`WorkParameters`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkerParameters) but you can only read them with [`WorkerParameters#getTags()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkerParameters#getTags()).

**It is not possible to add tags to an existing `WorkRequest`**

Maybe you can use other methods to add some information to a `Worker` like the [`ListenableWorker#setProgressAsync(androidx.work.Data)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#setProgressAsync(androidx.work.Data)). But it really depends on what are you trying to achieve.